# Is it possible to drag and drop an element from a different page to a Droppable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scriptaculous

I am trying to get the following requirement to work. I have a test page that has a Droppable area.

```
<%= drop_receiving_element(
 "basket",
 :onDrop => "function(element) { alert(element) }",
 :url => { :action => "create" }
)%>
```

What I want to achieve, is to be able to drop any links from another browser tab/window onto the Droppable and record that link. Bear in mind that these links will be arbitrary and out of my control so I can't decorate them as Draggable. Is this achievable or am I barking up the wrong tree?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible I'm afraid. Two browsers = two doms. Maybe possible with google gears, silverlight, and java but not js.

http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/default.asp

Comment: Thanks I see; although I can't understand the difficulty, since you're dropping an element, not the entire dom tree. Surely if you can arbitrarily add an element into your dom, dropping one in shouldn't be an issue. I guess I have to use an applet for this ? <shudder>